# Automatically collected events in GA4 are not displaying their automatically collected parameters

Tags: events, parameters, analytics, google-analytics-4

When in GA4, across all properties within my account. When clicking through Reports > Events > {Event Name} when it is an automatically collected event (or enhanced measurement) ie. page_view, no automatically collected parameters are able to be seen or selected via the dropdown (when seeing users within the last 30 mins), however, the values seem to be there. Any ideas as to why this is missing?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjxZ2.png)

Documentation obviously states that this is automatic and thus no custom dimensions/metrics need to be defined.

Enhanced measurement is also on.

Comment: what parameter you expect to see as the page_view's parameter name?